# Unable to install snap packages

Tags: snap

I have tried installing snap store or any other snap packages but i keep getting an error : error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Mount snap “snap-store” (558) (snap “snap-store” assumes unsupported
  features: snapd2.43 (try to update snapd and refresh the core snap))

I’ve tried to both remove snap a reinstall it, I have tried updating snap and everything seems to be fine and yet it will still not install snap packages.

snap version:

1. snap    2.37.4-1+b1
2. snapd   2.37.4-1+b1
3. series  16
4. deepin  20.3
5. kernel  5.10.60-amd64-desktop

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Comment: snap-store and spotify

Comment: try `sudo snap refresh core; sudo snap install core snapd` and then installing `snap-store` and `spotify`?

Comment: i am getting an error: cannot install "core", "snapd": cannot install snapd snap on a model without a base snap yet

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge snapd`
`sudo apt-get install snapd`, purge it and re install it and try

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please add output of `apt-cache policy snapd` .

Comment: Are you using Debian 10 (Buster)? [Because the package version would suggest so.](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/snapd_2.37.4-1+b1_amd64.deb.html)

Comment: deepin is built on debian 10

Comment: Ok, that explains. Unfortunately, other Debian-derived distros are off-topic here. Try [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are running an **ancient*** version of snapd - current version is 2.53.4**.

As suggested in comment, purge and reinstall snapd to fix this:

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

Be sure to update your packages regularly, either by unattended upgrades, or by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

* *Software older than 1 year is in fact ancient.*

** *This was written under the assumption that the question is about Ubuntu, which unfortunately isn't the case*

Comment: It is not ancient. Version number indicates that it is not official Ubuntu package - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=snapd .

Comment: [Snap 2.37.4 was released 27 Feb 2019](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/releases?page=6) - so yeah it's ancient. But you're probably right it isn't Ubuntu either.